# nnGraph multi-GPU Torch

Tags: deep-learning, torch, multi-gpu

**This question is about making any nnGraph network run on multiple GPUs and not specific to the following network instance**

I am trying to train a network which is constructed with nnGraph. The backward diagram is attached. I am trying to run the parallelModel (see code or fig Node 9) in a multi-GPU setting. If I attach the parallel model to a nn.Sequential container and then create a DataParallelTable it works in a multi-GPU setting (without nnGraph). However, after attaching it to nnGraph I get an error. The backward pass works if I train on a single GPU (setting true to false in the if statements), but in a multi-GPU setting I get an error "gmodule.lua:418: attempt to index local 'gradInput' (a nil value)". I think Node 9 in backward pass should run on multiple-GPUs, however that's not happening.  Creating DataParallelTable on nnGraph didn't work for me, however I thought atleast putting internal Sequential networks in a DataParallelTable would work. Is there some other way to split the initial data which is being passed to nnGraph so that it runs on multiple-GPUs?

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'
require 'cudnn'
require 'cunn'
require 'cutorch'
require 'nngraph'

data1 = torch.ones(4,20):cuda()
data2 = torch.ones(4,10):cuda()

tmodel = nn.Sequential()
tmodel:add(nn.Linear(20,10))
tmodel:add(nn.Linear(10,10))
parallelModel = nn.ParallelTable()
parallelModel:add(tmodel)
parallelModel:add(nn.Identity())
parallelModel:add(nn.Identity())

model = parallelModel
if true then
  local function sharingKey(m)
     local key = torch.type(m)
     if m.__shareGradInputKey then
        key = key .. ':' .. m.__shareGradInputKey
     end
     return key
  end

  -- Share gradInput for memory efficient backprop
  local cache = {}
  model:apply(function(m)
     local moduleType = torch.type(m)
     if torch.isTensor(m.gradInput) and moduleType ~= 'nn.ConcatTable' then
        local key = sharingKey(m)
        if cache[key] == nil then
           cache[key] = torch.CudaStorage(1)
        end
        m.gradInput = torch.CudaTensor(cache[key], 1, 0)
     end
  end)
end

if true then
  cudnn.fastest = true
  cudnn.benchmark = true

  -- Wrap the model with DataParallelTable, if using more than one GPU
  local gpus = torch.range(1, 2):totable()
  local fastest, benchmark = cudnn.fastest, cudnn.benchmark

  local dpt = nn.DataParallelTable(1, true, true)
     :add(model, gpus)
     :threads(function()
        local cudnn = require 'cudnn'
        cudnn.fastest, cudnn.benchmark = fastest, benchmark
     end)
  dpt.gradInput = nil

  model = dpt:cuda()
end


newmodel = nn.Sequential()
newmodel:add(model)

input1 = nn.Identity()()
input2 = nn.Identity()()
input3 = nn.Identity()()

out = newmodel({input1,input2,input3})

r1 = nn.NarrowTable(1,2)(out)
r2 = nn.NarrowTable(2,2)(out)

f1 = nn.JoinTable(2)(r1)
f2 = nn.JoinTable(2)(r2)

n1 = nn.Sequential()
n1:add(nn.Linear(20,5))

n2 = nn.Sequential()
n2:add(nn.Linear(20,5))  

f11 = n1(f1)
f12 = n2(f2)

foutput = nn.JoinTable(2)({f11,f12})

g = nn.gModule({input1,input2,input3},{foutput})
g = g:cuda()


g:forward({data1, data2, data2})
g:backward({data1, data2, data2}, torch.rand(4,10):cuda())
```

[image: Backward Pass]

The code in the "if" statements is taken from [Facebook's ResNet implementation](https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch/blob/master/models/init.lua)

Comment: Have you considered to use tensorflow? Have you come with a solution?

Comment: I switched back to Caffe after spending 5-6 months with Torch. Caffe has most of the vision code/models I need and now its python layer also supports multi-GPU option, so currently I don't see a reason to switch from Caffe. If everyone starts to use tensorflow and I can't find models/code in Caffe any more, I'll consider switching.